# CodeIgniter - How do I do Pagination?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I've look through lots of question asked about Pagination but I can't really understand how Pagination works. 
I need Pagination to work on `index()` and when user enter date range `searchdate()`.
In my Controller:

```
public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('ReportModel');
}

public function index()
{
   $orders=new ReportModel;
   $data['data']=$orders->get_orders();
   $this->load->view('includes/header');
   $this->load->view('Report/view',$data);
   $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}

public function searchDate()
{
   $orders=new ReportModel;
   $searchfrom = $this->input->post('searchDateFrom');
   $searchto = $this->input->post('searchDateTo');
   $data['data']=$orders->get_orders($searchfrom,$searchto);

   $this->load->view('includes/header');
   $this->load->view('Report/view',$data);
   $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

In my Model:

```
 public function get_orders(){
    $searchDateFrom = $this->input->post("searchDateFrom");
    $searchDateTo = $this->input->post("searchDateTo");
    $this->db->select('platform,id,no,date,printed_date');
    $this->db->from('orders');

    if(!empty($searchDateFrom) || !empty($searchDateTo) || !empty($searchPlatform)){
        if (!empty($searchDateFrom)) {
            $this->db->where('date >= ', $this->input->post("searchDateFrom"));
        }
        if (!empty($searchDateTo)) {
            $this->db->where('date <= ', $this->input->post("searchDateTo")." 23:59:59");
        }          
    }

    $this->db->order_by("date", "desc");
    $this->db->limit(300);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
 }
```

In my View:

```
<div class="pull-right">
        <form class="form-inline" role="search" action="<?php echo base_url('estoreReport/searchDate')?>" method = "post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Order Date From" name = "searchDateFrom" ">
              <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Order Date To" name = "searchDateTo" ">                    
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default " type="submit" value = "searchDateTo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </form>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Platform</th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>No</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Printed Date</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <?php foreach ($data as $d) { ?>
      <tr>
      <td ><?php echo $d->platform; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d->id; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d->no; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d->date; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d->printed_date; ?></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I've read CodeIgniter documentation, and know that I should put the configurations in the controller.

```
 public function pagination($count){
     $this->load->library('pagination');

     $config['base_url'] = base_url('/order/Report/');
     $config['total_rows'] = $count;
     $config['per_page'] = 100;
     $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
     $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
     $config["num_links"] = ;
     $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
     $config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;
     $page = ($this->uri->segment($config["uri_segment"] )) ? $this->uri->segment($config["uri_segment"] ) : 0;

     $this->pagination->initialize($config);

     $pagination = $this->pagination->create_links();

     return array($page, $config['per_page'], $pagination);
 }
```

But I'm still not sure how to do modify other parts of my controller, model and view. I'm a new CodeIgniter learner here, this is my testing page only, please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should look like this:

```
public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('ReportModel', 'orders');
  $this->load->library('pagination');
}

public function index($offset = 0)
{
    $data['data']=$this->orders->get_orders($search = array(), $offset);
    $config['total_rows'] = $data['total_rows'] = $this->orders->get_orders($search = array(), $offset, true);
    $config['base_url'] = base_url('/order/index/');
    $config['per_page'] = 100;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

   $this->load->view('includes/header');
   $this->load->view('Report/view',$data);
   $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

Then your model should be changed to also be able to paginate your results:

```
public function get_orders($search = array(), $offset = 0, $count = false){
    $searchDateFrom = $search["searchDateFrom"];
    $searchDateTo = $search["searchDateTo"];
    $this->db->select('platform,id,no,date,printed_date');
    $this->db->from('orders');

    if(!empty($searchDateFrom) || !empty($searchDateTo) || !empty($searchPlatform)){
        if (!empty($searchDateFrom)) {
            $this->db->where('date >= ', $this->input->post("searchDateFrom"));
        }
        if (!empty($searchDateTo)) {
            $this->db->where('date <= ', $this->input->post("searchDateTo")." 23:59:59");
        }          
    }

    $this->db->order_by("date", "desc");
    if ( !$count ) {
        $this->db->limit(100, $offset);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();

 }
```

Comment: do i need to modify my view ?

Comment: it has ` Undefined property: EstoreReport::$orders` on my controller

Comment: and also `Call to a member function get_orders() on a non-object` in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Check these:

[codeigniter pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44983186/i-make-pagination-but-it-cant-limit-post-per-page-codeigniter/44983278#44983278)

[codeigniter pagination 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578611/codeigniter-pagination-url-not-correctly-generated/46580821#46580821)

I have given answers to the question for pagination in Codeigniter on StackOverflow. These links have the full description. Hopefully it will help

Comment: i dont understand about the model part. how should i modify it

Comment: have you check the codeigniter pagination 2 link given above?

Comment: `$qr = $this>db->get('TABLENAME', $per_page, $this->uri->segment(3));` what does this means ?

Comment: it is setting limit and offset. $per_page has the limit value i.e., which you have defined in $config in controller and the third parameter is for passing offset i.e., how many rows to be skipped as it have shown on previous pages

Comment: You can understand this by putting `echo $this->db->last_query();` after this line to get understand what query this line is generating.

Comment: I have error on this `config['total_rows'] = $this->ReportModel->record_count(); ` the message `Call to undefined method EstoreReportModel::record_count()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179606/discussion-between-hatched-and-akshit-ahuja).